# MWS before giving submit feed, can we check if it is currently throttling?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I have multiple process to submit feed for product, price and quantity data.

It throttles and I cant keep track of number of requests for feed submission is given.

Is there a simple way to know if feed is throttling currently.

And if not, and I submit into throttled feed, can amazon Block me for too many requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your architecture, but something I would do if I had time to rewrite my systems is I would store each feed in a queue like SQS.  It wouldn't matter where the feed originated from, they would be stored in a queue.  Then have a service set on some type of timer that will read the next feed from your queue, and process it.  If it gets throttled, pause for a bit until your quota increases.   In doing this, you'll only process a single feed at a time and you don't have to orchestrate multiple feeds being processed from multiple places at a single time.

If you want to run multiple instances of your processing service, you'll have to do an orchestration between your threads.  That could get tricky, but would allow you to process through your queue quicker.  All depends on how much you're trying to push through.

Only delete the feed in the queue when it's successful.

There are hourly quotas on the Feeds API.  You'll have to keep track of that in your service.  Just ++ your counter each time you successfully call MWS.  I don't think they'll block you (as a punishment), more or less they'll just return failures until you have quota available.

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IT/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html

Hope that helps.